# get rid of border in Card Component React native element

Tags: react-native

In the [Card Component](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/card.html#dividerstyle) for react native elements

I'm trying to get rid of the border by setting the border to 0 and borderColor to transparent but there's still a gray outline

```
      <Card
        containerStyle={{borderWidth: 0, borderColor: 'transparent', elevation: 0}}
        title='HELLO WORLD'
        image={require('../images/pic2.jpg')}>
        <Text style={{marginBottom: 10}}>
          The idea with React Native Elements is more about component structure than actual design.
        </Text>  
      </Card>
```

Thought it might have been box shadow, but that's not it either

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've got the same issue, and I've found that border appears because the Card element has an elevation default setted to 1

You can override this (for android) :

```html
<Card containerStyle={{elevation:0, backgroundColor:#123}}/>
```

and in IOS:

```js
const styles = {
  container: {
    shadowColor: 'rgba(0,0,0, .2)',
    shadowOffset: { height: 0, width: 0 },
    shadowOpacity: 0, //default is 1
    shadowRadius: 0//default is 1
  }
}
```

```html
<Card containerStyle={styles.container} />
```

Answer (score 6):

Its late but it seems that a lot of people still searching for the Answer.

`React Native Elements` by default have set both `borderWidth` and `shadow Props`, so in order to remove border completely you need to remove both `Border` and `Shadow`.

```js
<Card containerStyle={styles.cardCnt}>
    <Text>Content</Text>
</Card>

const styles = {
   cardCnt: {
        borderWidth: 0, // Remove Border

        shadowColor: 'rgba(0,0,0, 0.0)', // Remove Shadow for iOS
        shadowOffset: { height: 0, width: 0 },
        shadowOpacity: 0,
        shadowRadius: 0,
        
        elevation: 0 // Remove Shadow for Android
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like react native elements' Card component has a grey border in all of the examples I've seen. I'd suggest building your own card component. Start with something like this and then style it however you want. This one has a bit of shadow which you can turn off by passing it a noShadow prop.

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const Card = (props) => {
  let shadowStyle = {
    shadowColor: COLORS.grey3,
    shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 0 },
    shadowOpacity: .5,
    shadowRadius: 12,
    elevation: 1,
  }
  if (props.noShadow) {
    shadowStyle = {}
  }
  return (
    <View style={[styles.containerStyle, props.style, shadowStyle]}>
      {props.children}
    </View>
  );
};


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  containerStyle: {
    padding: 10,
    marginHorizontal: 10,
    backgroundColor: COLORS.white,
    borderRadius: 3,
  }
})

export { Card };
```

Then when you want to use it just

```
import { Card } from './yourCustomCardFile'
```

Then in your render method

```
<Card>
<Text>Any content you want to include on the card</Text>
<Text>More content that you want on the card</Text>
</Card>
```

Answer (score 1):

set `elevation` to 0 and `borderColor` to `white` like this

`<Card containerStyle={{ elevation: 0, borderColor: "white" }}>`

Answer (score 0):

set to screen background color

Dirty but problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I got rid of the same issue by simply applying the following styles to Card element inside the slider.

```
const cardStyles: React.CSSProperties = {
 display: 'flex',
 justifyContent: 'center',
 alignItems: 'center',
 height: '200px', // Adjust the card height as needed
 width: '100%', // Set width to ensure 5 items are shown in web view
 borderColor: 'white', // Set the border color to white
 borderWidth: '0px', // Set border width to 0
 borderRadius: '0px', // Set border radius to 0
 boxShadow: 'none', // Remove any box shadow
};
```